# Why has keys of array changed when I take them by config()?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of months with keys on config:

```
return [
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February',
    '03' => 'March',
    '04' => 'April',
    '05' => 'May',
    '06' => 'June',
    '07' => 'July',
    '08' => 'August',
    '09' => 'September',
    '10' => 'October',
    '11' => 'November',
    '12' => 'December',
];
```

When I get them by `dd(config('months'));` the result is:

```
[
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February',
    '03' => 'March',
    '04' => 'April',
    '05' => 'May',
    '06' => 'June',
    '07' => 'July',
    '08' => 'August',
    '09' => 'September',
    '0' => 'October',
    '1' => 'November',
    '2' => 'December',
];
```

Why has this changed? I have no idea...

Comment: you may be doing something wrong that's why you are getting this. Because you will always get the same values that you set.

Comment: somewhere down the line modification done by some code, `01=> can be 1` (if you write it as integer) but `10=>can not be 0 in any case`. so fault is in your code

Comment: I checked it in Laravel 5.1. It seems that the 10, 11, and 12 keys are automatically cast to integers indeed. wired. However, it doesn't explain your case, where 1 is trimmed

Comment: try giving integer values by removing quotes and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your input will be the key, but there is in my opinion a simple helper function that can do the same, with help from Carbon.

```
function getMonth($key) {
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $date->setMonth($key);
    return $date->format('F');
}

$month = $this->getMonth('02'); // will return "February"
```

Comment: I used carbon instead of that array. Thank you

Comment: Way easier solution imo. thanks for the accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe used config set

```
config(['months' => $new_array]);
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that this code works different?

Comment: Where does `$new_array` come from? And why is that needed?